# MySQL Workbench 5.6 crashes on connection to localhost

Tags: php, html, css, sql, xml

I'm running Apache 2.2 and MySQL Workbench, and using PHP to access the database.

The problem is, when I try to open the database I've made, MySQL Workbench can't seem to connect to the localhost at port 80, and the program stops responding.

How can I fix this?

Update: After some time of the program simply not responding, it gave me this error message:

```
"Unhandled exception: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet', system error 10060 (code 2013)"
```

Answer (score 0):

A wamp installation has a lot of issues. Instead, you can run a Virtual Machine with ubuntu and run there LAMP. it is way more reliable than running wamp that is not supposed to be "equal" in terms of your production environment - that for sure is linux based OS. Also, keep in mind that programs such skype blocks the port 80 and 443. Search what programs are using the port for mysql... that's why I don't develop AMP apps under windows, but under linux.